# Flutter , camera application running in the background

Tags: flutter, background, camera, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have a face detection project with the camera ,

I want the application to run in the background, so when you press the back button or home button, the application will run. but when i put the app in the background my camera turns off and i can't recognize a face

I guess I need to write service, but the examples on the internet are confusing and I don't have much experience in java and kotlin .

what should i do , Thank you